# Query mysql for 2 tables with summary of items per month sold including items that are not sold

Tags: mysql, database

Looking for some help, so badly. So I have 2 tables which are:

1. transactions
2. Allocations

My **transaction** table contains these ff. columns:

transaction_id(int), 
alloc_id(int),
month_sold(varchar),
quantity_sold(int)

My **Allocations** table contains these ff. columns:

alloc_id(int),item_allocation(int),  item_name(varchar)

I just want to display the summary of items sold per month and not sold and also their allocations. Badly need some help. Thank you in advance!

I tried this, but I cannot get the allocations that are not sold.

```
SELECT transaction.transaction_id, allocations.item_allocation, 
    sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'JANUARY', quantity_sold,0)) AS JAN, 
    sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'FEBRUARY', quantity_sold, 0)) AS FEB, 
    sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'MARCH', quantity_sold, 0)) AS MAR 
FROM transaction 
JOIN allocations ON allocations.alloc_id = transaction.alloc_id 
GROUP BY transaction.month_sold
```

Comment: How are the two tables related? There doesn't seem to be a foreign key in either of them.

Comment: Is there an `item` table that can be used to relate `transaction.item_id` with `allocations.item_name`? Why doesn't `allocations` use `item_id` instead of the name?

Comment: You need to join the tables, then use `SUM(quantity_sold)` and `GROUP BY month_sold`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you the response, I edited my question. allocation_id is the foreign key for the transcation table.

Comment: OK, so now it should be easy. Just join the tables and do the grouping and sum. What's getting in your way, other than you not knowing the basic concepts?

Comment: SO isn't a programming school, you have to learn the basics somewhere else. Then post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: copy sir, so I got some from the web but I cannot get the allocations that not sold.

SELECT transaction.transaction_id, allocations.item_allocation, 
                sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'JANUARY', quantity_sold,0))  AS JAN,
                sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'FEBRUARY', quantity_sold, 0))  AS FEB,
                sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'MARCH', quantity_sold, 0))  AS MAR
                 FROM transaction JOIN allocations ON allocations.alloc_id = transaction.alloc_id GROUP BY transaction.month_sold

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you should be grouping by `alloc_id`, not `month_sold`.

Subtract the sum of items sold from the allocation to get the items not sold.

```
SELECT allocations.alloc_id, 
    sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'JANUARY', quantity_sold,0)) AS JAN, 
    sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'FEBRUARY', quantity_sold, 0)) AS FEB, 
    sum(if (transaction.month_sold = 'MARCH', quantity_sold, 0)) AS MAR,
    allocations.item_allocation - SUM(quantity_sold) AS not_sold
FROM transaction 
JOIN allocations ON allocations.alloc_id = transaction.alloc_id 
GROUP BY allocations.alloc_id
```

Comment: omgg, thank you sir. I just like to add up if also the items that are not sold would be disaplyed. I revised the code but cant get through it.

Comment: Edit the question. Add some sample data and the desired result.